# Can we use SVG/Vector image for flood fill algorithm? If yes then how?

Tags: android, native

I implemented QueueLinearFloodFill Algorithm it works fast for me, but the images I am using are .PNG type, all good quality images are also returning in the issue that white part is left uncolored at border. So Can I use SVG/Vector type. and if yes how.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Since one is pixel oriented and the other is vector oriented, no, not really.

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? you want to change the color of a vector drawable? so tint it or use a color filter, you want use some gradient instead of solid color? then use a `Shader`

Comment: @pskink I want to implement [kind of app like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kidsplaylearning.apps.colorbook&hl=en). I used floodfill algorithm and png format Images and filled color in shapes but it is leaving edges uncolored. So can anyone please help me with it

Comment: did you find any solution yet?

Comment: did you find any solution yet?